# Visual Studio restoring solution to previous point

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have a VS2012 solution that I have been developing for quite some time now. I regularly (at least once a week) do a check-in of all the changes to TFS. The solution is made of 6 or 7 projects.

Right now I am having a bit of a problem. I need to get the entire solution as-it-was in a previous point in time. I know what changeset I need to get, i just don't know how to accomplish that.
I tried doing a rollback but nearly had a heart attack because I lost several projects. Seems that doing that only gets the files that were commited on that changeset.

I tried going through the browser and download the project as it was on the changeset that I want but when I opened the solution some projects are missing it's almost the same as doing the rollback. But I am sure that it was not how the solution was when I did that check-in.

I must be doing something wrong.

I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough, I'll be glad to provide some more info if necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do check-ins **much** more frequently than once a week. Do small commits that encompass a single new feature or change. It's generally a good practice to commit several times a day.

That said, the feature you're looking for is "Get Specific Version". You can right-click on a folder, mouse over "Advanced", and it's right there.

You can then specify the changeset, and it'll pull down the version of source code from that point in time.

If you have work in progress, you'll want to create a shelveset containing all your work in progress prior to getting a specific version -- it will overwrite anything that you haven't checked in yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That does not work. When I tried doing that I only got the files that were checked-in on that time. Some files got "lost". I really don't know how to explain it better.

Comment: Hi Daniel. I found the solution to my problem. Instead of selecting the solution and doing what you specified, which did not work. Instead I selected all the projects and did "Get specific version". This worked. I don't know what the difference is but I'm glad it's solved now.